# Can we brand a mobile app?

Tags: visualforce, mobile, customer-portal

I am very new to mobile development.  Is it possible to brand a mobile app hosted on force.com?  We would like to have our customers download "MyCompanyApp" that runs on force.com instead of Salesforce1 from the app store .  We want the same look and feel of Salesforce1.  Ideally we would have some type of customer portal where the user would login and see some information on Visualforce pages.  What is the best practice here?  Where is a good starting point?

Answer (score 0):

As a starting point, I suggest you look at a free App on the App exchange called [Private App Exchange](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B4VlZEAV), a Corporate App Store that allows you to distribute Apps to your employees.

> With Private AppExchange, you can distribute any app, to any employee, on any device through a central, secure store. Use Salesforce Identity to grant employees instant access to the apps they need. Customize your store with your categories and branding.

The Salesforce1 App can be custom branded for your org. See [Change Salesforce1 App Branding for Your Organization](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_sf1_branding_edit.htm&language=en_US) and [How Salesforce1 Branding Works](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1appadmin.meta/salesforce1appadmin/s1_admin_guide_branding.htm) for more on the details of the extent to which it can be branded and how to implement the changes.